# HTML won't link up to CSS when I open it again

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I linked the CSS correctly when I created my HTML file, but then when I try to edit the CSS the other day, it just didn't update my HTML file and I did save it of course. One way I can get around this is by deleting the CSS in my `htdocs` and creating a new stylesheet with the exact same contents then linking the new one to my HTML. Can you guys tell me why is this happening and how can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: can you add some codes,or portion of code where you link the style sheet

Comment: after complete the uploading did you check the source code ?

Comment: Most probably you are facing this because of caching. One more thing that you can check is if you are running WAMP or XAMP then restart it.

Comment: other option your browser catch , clear it and check it

Comment: As already mentioned, the problem is most likely the caching. Could you show the headers send with the css file. I would assume the server sends an `expires`, `max-age` or `min-fresh` information to the client which will tell the client that the resource does not need to be refetched for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is with cache. You can try running the site in an **incognito/private window** of your browser.

You can also inspect the page and see if the new styles are loaded. You can also try **Empty Cache and Hard Reload** option when you right click the reload button on chrome browser while inspecting.

Comment: I actually just clear browsing data after that I reload my page an then it worked. Thanks. For future references ill use "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" Thanks, Vishnu!

Answer (score 0):

one way you can prevent it is by doing all your css in the actual html file like so

```
<head><style></style></head>
```

Comment: Yes of course that's a one way to do it. But my professor wants us to use CSS externally. Thanks anyways

Comment: oh ok well hope you get the help you need